# preg_replace or str_replace Php Replace by position

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, preg-replace

Let's say I got this string:

```
$str = "alemylaife";
```

(I know it's misspelled, all my life)

Now how can I replace

"ale" without replacing whatever comes after "ale" that also contains the same letters?

Let's say I got this arrays:

```
$replace = Array("a","l","e");  
$with = Array("wh","at","ever");

$str = str_replace($replace,$with,$str);
echo $str;
```

this will print:

```
 whatevermyatwhifever
```

How could I stop the str_replace for replacing the letters after "ale"?
Maybe I got to trim the 3 first letters then replacing them then join the trimmed strings?

EDIT: I'm going to try to express myself clearer.
I want only the three (3) first letters to be replaced IF they contain A THEN L THEN whateverletter so, ala ale ald alr aly. Those are the letters that I want to be replaced. I don't want letters after them to be affected.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion for more fancy rules at http://php.net/str_replace ? Also your question is not clear. In it's current form I see a lot of chance that it *technically can not be answered* because the problem is not well defined (there are more than one answer possible, but you need a specific one of those but don't tell which one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question isn't really clear. Assuming you want to replace "ale" with "whatever" (correct me if I'm wrong), then you could use preg_replace to limit the number of replacements.

**Example 1:** (replace the first occurrence of "ale")

```
preg_replace("/ale/", "whatever", "alemylaife", 1)
> whatevermylaife
```

**Example 2:** (replace only if the string *starts* with "ale")

```
preg_replace("/^ale/", "whatever", "alemylaife", 1)
> whatevermylaife

preg_replace("/^ale/", "whatever", "lolalemylaife", 1)
> lolalemylaife
```

**EDIT:** You edited your question to provide better details, I would use:

```
// match a string that begins with "al" and then a character (case in-sensitive)
preg_replace("/^al[a-z]/i", "whatever", "alemylaife");
```

Answer (score 1):

Outputs F because A is replaced with B, then B is replaced with C, and so on...
Finally E is replaced with F, because of left to right replacements.

```
$search  = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
$replace = array('B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');
$subject = 'A';
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
```

Outputs: apearpearle pear
For the same reason mentioned above

```
$letters = array('a', 'p');
$fruit   = array('apple', 'pear');
$text    = 'a p';
$output  = str_replace($letters, $fruit, $text);
echo $output;
```

And for further reference check  http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear to me for which kind of string function you're looking here.

```
$string = "alemylaife";
```

You then write about the letters `"ale"`. It is not clear whether you mean the sequence `"ale"` or you mean just the letters, any order, any count until each of those (`"a"`, `"e"`, `"l"`) has been matched at least one time.

That would be two very different things. Let's take the first one, it's more easy:

```
// search for needle

$needle = 'ale';
$pos = strpos($string, $needle);

if (false === $pos) {
    $before = '';
    $after  = $string;
} else {
    $before = substr($string, 0, $pos);
    $after  = substr($string, $pos + strlen($needle));
}
```

You can then run the replacement on the part you want to and then concatenate afterwards.

The second variant needs more processing logic. It could be done by finding the first position of each character and the largest match is then the position. If any of the searches fails, it fails. This would replace the `str_pos` call from the first example, actually it is running it then multiple times:

```
// search for character group

$group = str_split($needle);

$pos = false;
foreach (str_split($needle) as $character) {
    $test = strpos($string, $character);
    if (false === $test) {
        $pos = false;
        break;
    }
    $test += strlen($character);
    if ($test >= $pos) {
        $pos = $test;
    }
}
```

At the end, `$pos` contains the position of the first letter which is the last matching letter of the whole group.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have fixed searches and replacements? A machine can't know which `ale` string you mean.

You could widen your search till you have a unique match, e.g. replace `alem` by `all m` or [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) using the limit parameter set to 1. Of course this would always replace the first occurrence.